# How can the address of this member variable change in objective-c when the object containing it dosen't?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while now and cannot work out why it is happening. It seems to only happen when "Archiving" the application and running on a device, not when debugging an application.

I have two classes:

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    EAGLView * glView;  // A view for OpenGL ES rendering
}

@interface EAGLView : UIView
{
@public
    GLuint framebuffer;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame pixelFormat:(NSString*)fformat depthFormat:(GLuint)depth stencilFormat:(GLuint)stencil preserveBackbuffer:(bool)retained scale:(float)fscale msaaMaxSamples:(GLuint)maxSamples;
```

and I am intitializing one object as so:

```
glView = [ EAGLView alloc ];
glView = [ glView initWithFrame:rect pixelFormat:strColourFormat depthFormat:iDepthFormat stencilFormat:iStencilFormat preserveBackbuffer:NO scale:scale msaaMaxSamples:iMSAA ];
NSLog(@"%s:%d &glView %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, glView );
NSLog(@"%s:%d &glView->framebuffer %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, &glView->framebuffer );
```

With initWithFrame looking like:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    /* ... */
{
    if( ( self = [super initWithFrame:frame] ) )
    {
        /* ... */
    }
    NSLog(@"%s:%d &self %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, self );
    NSLog(@"%s:%d &framebuffer %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, &framebuffer );

    return self;
}
```

The log shows:

```
EAGLView.mm:399 self 0x134503e90
EAGLView.mm:401 &framebuffer 0x134503f68
AppController.mm:277 glView 0x134503e90
AppController.mm:281 &glView->framebuffer 0x134503f10
```

How can the address of this member variable change when the object that contains it does not?

Comment: Is framebuffer allocated in the init method, when yu print it?

Comment: framebuffer is just an unsigned int member, I don't think I need to "alloc" it do I?

Comment: No. Maybe is just a way of how iOS map those variables, I think it's hard to look for the "right" explanation

Answer (score 1):

Why not use pointers instead? You are guaranteed the address will be the same.  Modify EAGLView to be like

```
@interface EAGLView : UIView 
{ 
@public
    GLuint *framebuffer; 
}
```

Print out the address of the `framebuffer` as:

```
NSLog(@"%s:%d &glView->framebuffer %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, glView->framebuffer );
```

And inside `initWithFrame` do something like:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    unsigned int fbo= opengl_get_framebuffer();
    framebuffer = &fbo;
    NSLog(@"%s:%d &framebuffer %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, framebuffer );
}
```

Now the address of the framebuffer SHOULD be the same!